# Can we move the pointer of ofstream back and forth for output to file?

Tags: c++, file, output, ofstream

I need to output results to a file that has a predefined format. The columns look like this:

TIME COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 ...

I am using ofstream. I have to output results line by line. However, the case can be that results for certain columns may not be available at a certain time. The order of the results may also not be sorted.

I can control the spacing between the columns while initially specifying the headers.

I guess my question is: Is it possible to move the ofstream pointer back and forth horizontally per line?

What I tried so far:
1) find current position of ofstream pointer using:

`long pos = fout.tellp()`

2) calculate the position to be shifted based on spacing:

```
spacing = column_spacing * column_number 
long newpos = pos + spacing
```

3) then use seekp() to move pointer:

```
fout.seekp(newpos)
```

4) provide output:

```
fout << "output"
```

This does not work. Basically, the pointer does not move. The idea is to make my ofstream fout move back and forth if possible. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to control it.

Some information about the output: I am computing the elevation angle of GPS satellites in the sky over time. Hence, there are 32 columns synonymous to number of GPS satellites in total. At any point in time, not all satellites are visible and hence the need to skip some satellites/columns. Also, the list of elevation of satellites may not be arranged in ascending order due to the limitations of observation file. Hope that helps in drawing the situation.

An example of desired output. The header (TIME, SAT1, ... SAT32) is defined prior to the output of results and is not part of the question here. The spacing between each column is controlled during definition of the headers (lets say 15 spaces between each column). The output can be truncated to 1 decimal place. A new line occurs once all results at current time t are written. Then I process the observations for time t+1 and then write the outputs again, and so on.  Hence the writing occurs in an epochwise manner. Satellite elevation is stored in a vector(double) and satellite number is stored in a vector(int). Both vectors are of same length. I just need to write them to a file. For the example below, the output of time is in seconds and satellite elevation is in degrees:

```
TIME   SAT1   SAT2   SAT3   ...   SAT12   SAT13  ...   SAT32
1      34.3          23.2         12.2                 78.2
2      34.2          23.1         12.3                 78.2
3      34.1   11.3   23.0                              78.3
```

And so on... As you may notice, satellite elevations may or may not be available, all depends on the observations. Lets also assume that the size of output and efficiency is not of priority here. Based on 24 hours of observations, the output file size can reach upto 5-10 MB's.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Give a concrete specification (in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation), and an example, of the desired output.

Comment: Without telling more about your output, your question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: Even with the edit, your question stays unclear. You should specify your output precisely (EBNF notation is helpful), give some example of output -at least a few lines- and give some estimates of its size (megabytes or terabytes of data).

Comment: Are `SAT1` and `...` part of the output? You need to **specify the output with *much more* detail**. Explain also who would read your output (what program, since files are *always* read by some program - perhaps as simple as [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)..). Also, explain on what OS are your running these programs

Comment: BTW you still don't define what your program does, and what is its inputs and outputs and features.

Comment: You probably need to spend many months in [learning to program](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) before being able to code your program. You should specify (in English, on paper) what your program does.

Comment: The output is only one part of the program. I did mention that I am computing the satellite elevation angles in an epochwise manner and I need to output them to a file. The inputs and processing occur separately and may not be useful to add here.

Comment: That is your (newbie) opinion, but it is wrong. The inputs, processing, outputs matter a lot!

Comment: Ok, I apologize for my newbie opinion. I am sure however that there are others in my situation who may also come across such an issue. How else will I learn if I am not allowed to make mistakes and ask questions. I know I have a long way to go but I am trying to learn here. No need to degrade my attempts. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should define *precisely* the format of your output. You did not define it in your question, but you should define that format (up to each space and newline) in some document (or comment).

Comment: BTW, why are you asking? Is is for some job in some satellite company? for a PhD work? A homework for some CS course?

Answer (score 4):

> Can we move the pointer of ofstream back and forth for output to file?

**NO**, You probably don't want to do that (even if it would be doable in principle; but that would be inefficient and very brittle to code, and nearly impossible to debug), in particular for a textual output whose width is variable (I am guessing that your COL<sub>i</sub> could have variable width, as usual in most textual format).  It looks that your approach is wrong.

The general way is to build in memory, as some graph of "objects" or "data structure", the entire representation of your output file. This is generally enough, unless you really need to output something huge.

If your typical textual output is of reasonable size (a few gigabytes at most) then representing the data as some internal data structure is worthwhile and it is very common practice.

If your textual output is huge (dozens of gigabytes or terabytes, which is really unlikely), then you won't be able to represent it in memory (unless you have a costly computer with a terabyte of RAM). However, you could use some database (perhaps [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)) to serve as internal representation.

In practice, **textual formats are always output in sequence** (from some internal representation) and textual files in those formats have a reasonable size (so it is uncommon to have a textual file of many gigabytes today; in such cases, databases -or splitting the output file in several pieces in some directory- are better).

<sup>Without specifying *precisely* your textual format (e.g. using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation) and giving an example - and some estimation of the output size-, your question is too broad, and you can only get hints like above.</sup>

> the output file size can reach upto 5-10 MB's

This is really tiny on current computers (even a cheap smartphone has a gigabyte of RAM). So build the data structure in memory, and output it at once when it is completed.

What [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) should you use depend upon your actual problem (and the inputs your program gets, and the precise output you want it to produce). Since you don't specify your program in your question, we cannot help. Probably C++ standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) could be useful (but this is just a guess).

You should read some introduction to programming (like [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)), then some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and read some good [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). You probably need to read something about compilation techniques (since they include parsing and outputting structured data), like the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Learning to program [takes](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) a lot of time.

<sup>C++ is really a *very difficult* programming language, and I believe it is not the best way to learn programming. Once you have learned a bit how to program, invest your time in learning C++. Your issues is not on `std::ostream` or C++ but on designing your program and its architecture correctly</sup>

BTW, if the output of your program is feeding some other program (and is not only or mostly for human consumption) you might use some established textual format, perhaps [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) (see also [this](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/xml/guide/xmlexample.html) example),  ....

> ```
>      2      34.2          23.1         12.3                 78.2
> ```

How significant are the spaces in the above line (what would happen if a space is inserted after the first `2` and another space is removed after `12.3`) ? Can a wide number like `3.14159265358979323846264` appear in your output? Or how many digits do you want? That should be documented *precisely* somewhere ! Are you allowed to improve the output format above (you might perhaps use some sign like `?` for missing numbers; that would make the output less ambiguous and more readable for humans and easier to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) by some other program)?

You need to define *precisely* (in English) the behavior of your program, including its input and output formats. An example of input and output is not a specification (it is just an example).

BTW, you may also want to code your program to provide several different output formats. For example, you could decide to provide CSV format for usage in speadsheets, JSON format for other data processing, [gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) output to get nice figures, [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) output to be able to insert your output in some technical report, [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) output to be usable thru a browser, etc. Once you have a good internal representation (as convenient data structures) of your computed data, outputting it in various formats is easy and very convenient.

Probably your domain (satellite processing) has defined some widely used data formats. Study them in detail (at least for inspiration on specifying your own output format).  I am not at all an expert of satellite data, but with google I quickly found examples like [*GEOSCIENCE AUSTRALIA
 (CCRS) LANDSAT THE MATIC MAPPER DIGITAL DATA FORMAT
DESCRIPTION*](http://www.ga.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0014/11741/GA18331.pdf) (in more than a hundred pages). You should specify your output format as precisely as they do (perhaps several dozens of pages in English, with a few pages of [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)), and [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) is a convenient notation for that (with a lot of additional explanations in English)

Look also for inspiration into other output data format descriptions.

You probably should, if you invent your output format, publish its specification (in English) so that other people could code programs taking your output as input to their code.

In many domains, data is much more valuable (i.e. costs much more, in € or US$) than the code processing it. This is why its format should be precisely documented. You need to specify that format so that a future programmer in 2030 could easily write a parser for it. So details matter a big lot. **Specify unambiguously your output format in great details** (in some English document).

Once you have specified that output format, coding the output routines from some good enough internal data representation is easy work (and don't require insane tricks like moving the file offset of the output). And a good enough specification of the output format is also a guideline in designing your internal data representations.

> Is it possible to move the ofstream pointer back and forth horizontally per line?

It might be doable, but it is so inefficient and error-prone (and impossible to debug) that in practice **you should never do that** (but instead, specify in details your output and code a simple sequential output routines, as all textual format related software do).

BTW, today we use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) in textual files, and a single [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character might span one (e.g. for some digit like `0` or latin letters like `E`) or several bytes (e.g. for accentuated letters like `é`, or cyrillic letters like `я`, or symbols like  `∀`, etc...) so replacing a single UTF8 character by a single other one could mean some byte insertion or deletion.

Notice that current file systems do not allow to *insert* characters or bytes or *delete* a span of characters in the middle of a file (for example, on Linux, there is no [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) allowing this) and do not really know about lines (the end of line is just a *convention*, e.g. `\n` byte on Linux). Programs doing that (like your favorite [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)) are *always* representing the data in memory. Today, a [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) is a sequence of bytes, and you can only append bytes at its end, or replace bytes in the middle (from the operating system's point of view); but insertion or deletion of bytes span in the middle of the file is not possible, and that is why a textual file is -in practice- always written sequentially, from start to end, without moving inside the current file offset (other than appending bytes at its end).

<sup>(if this is homework for some CS college or undergraduate course, I guess that your teacher is expecting you to define and document your output format)</sup>

Comment: As you may have noticed, I am new to C++ and programming in general. I will edit my question but here is some information about the output. I am computing the elevation angle of GPS satellites in the sky over time. Hence, there are 32 columns synonymous to number of GPS satellites in total. At any point in time, not all satellites are visible and hence the need to skip some satellites/columns. Also, the list of elevation of satellites may not be arranged in ascending order due to the limitations of observation file. Hope that helps in drawing the situation.

Comment: That should go into your question, and with a concrete example of output. But my hints above are worthwhile. You probably should keep in memory, in some data structure, all your data and once it is computed, output it at once. And you really should describe your output data with much more detail. If you are new to programming, read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). And it is important to *specify precisely* your output

Comment: I can perhaps store it all in an Eigen Matrix of 32 columns and then output it all at once, that is surely an option. I am also curious about how to solve it the other way with ofstream or other data structures as you have mentioned.

Comment: Your approach is wrong and confusing. Your issue is not the output routines (they are easy to code) but in defining the data structures needed for your problem. I gave several references, you'll need months to read them

Comment: I plan to read these references but I need to continue with my project as well. The results are available in a vector format and I just need to write them to a file. It is as if I am getting observations in real time, processing them, and writing the results to an output file. This is the idea.

Comment: Great. So define a data structure (probably using C++ `<vector>` and/or `<map>`) representing your data (and defining that data structure is the hard part of your work; coding the output routines is then easy). Then *specify in details* your output format. As the example I gave you shows, that could take dozens of pages in English. BTW, it is your best interest, if you invent that output format, to make its specification public and usable by others.

Comment: BTW [real time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) has some technical meaning. In some cases (notably very hard real-time) C++ is not possible; so "getting observation in real time" is not well defined (again, you should specify more in details what that exactly means: getting one observation every microsecond is not the same as getting one every two minutes; and a single observation could be a gigabyte of data - high resolution satellite imagery - or just a dozen of bytes). You should specify much more the problem you are solving (and that is part of the fun of programming)